# Bit Bucket and Git Bash Missing Edits from other Team Member

Tags: git

Another member merged with his edits and added a decent amount of work.  I was in the process of doing edits and did a commit and merged.  How can I get his edits onto my new work or how can you get my edits and add his work?  My work is currently on the master.

I have tried pulling to see if it would pull his, but still learning as this is my first class with it.